# Open Server Name in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have [this error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) and trying to follow these steps to solve it.

Step 2. says:

> In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click
>   the website that you want to modify.

I don't know where is server name and how to expand Web Sites. I'm using IIS 10.0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [getting started guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8).

I have also provided an annotated image for your reference.
 [image: annotated image]